# dockerhub retag existing image without creating a copy

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to retag my existing image with a new tag without creating a new image.

Following approach is not working :

`docker pull repo/image:1`

`docker pull repo/image:1 repo/image:1.0`

`docker push repo/image:1.0`

i wanted to change the existing tag of my image on dockerhub, but insted i am getting 2 images one with version 1 and one with 1.0.

How can i change tag from 1 to 1.0 without creating another copy on dockerhub.

Comment: Would you not just delete the `:1` tagged image? A tag is not a copy - it is just a shortcut name for the full image ID.

Comment: Go to dockerhub and delete the tag

Comment: @johnxf everytime i downlaod and change tag and upload again, does not sound good ,right, should be able to retag inplace and then upload new tagged image again  no ?

Comment: When you down load you are not removing the image from the server - it is still there. So as @JinnaBalu suggests you need to delete the `:1` tagged image via the UI or via the command line or whatever tools exist.

Answer (score 1):

This will re-tag repo/image:1 to repo/image:1.0 without creating a new image:

```
docker pull repo/image:1
docker tag repo/image:1 repo/image:1.0
docker push repo/image:1.0
```

Comment: did not wanted to create a new image, this will create a new image

Comment: This does NOT create a new image, it simply creates a new tag referencing the same image.